# Unity - Updating Font Size tags in TMPro Stylesheet on runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I have a style sheet set up in which I set up tags that set font size such as `<size=23px>`. Is it possible to somehow modify the stylesheet on runtime to change these sizes (even if I have to do it one by one)? It's for implementing a font size slider in the UI settings of the game (ideally I'd like to multiply each fontsize by a modifier).
Thank you

Edit: To clarify, I set the sizes via opening tags in the style sheets and I am looking to update these settings on runtime, NOT update the text size on the TextMeshProUGUI components!

I'm able to reference my default styleSheet directly. According to  https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.TMP_StyleSheet.html "GetStyle" retrieves "the Style matching the HashCode" (or name if I give it a string parameter). Once I get the style, however, I have very limited choice: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.TMP_Style.html?q=TMP_Style based on this, my best bet would be to query "styleOpeningDefinition".

I am able to get the opening tags via styleOpeningDefinition, and then find and replace the relevant number that denotes the size in the "<size="50px">" tag but it's a readonly property so I cant set it afterwards.

Here's the code:

```
TMP_Text text = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
TMP_Style style = styleSheet.GetStyle("H1");
openingTags = style.styleOpeningDefinition;
 
string[] size = openingTags.Split("px><cspace=");
string _splitString = size[0].Replace("<size=", "");
float _currentSize = float.Parse(_splitString);
_currentSize *= multiplier;
 
 
string _newTags = "<size=" + _currentSize + "px>" + size[1];
 
style.styleOpeningDefinition = _newTags;   //Property or indexer 'TMP_Style.styleOpeningDefinition' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
style.RefreshStyle();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Unity, you can use the UnityEngine.UI.Text component to change the font size of text elements on runtime. You can use the fontSize property of the Text component to change the font size.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FontSizeModifier : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;
    public float fontSizeModifier = 1f;

    void Update()
    {
        text.fontSize = (int)(text.fontSize * fontSizeModifier);
    }
}
```

This script will update the font size of the text element on every frame, multiplying the current font size by the fontSizeModifier variable.
You can use this script and attach it to the text element you want to modify, or you can create a list of texts and modify them all via a loop.

Comment: Thank you Pedro, I should have been clearer - the font sizes are all set via the stylesheet via opening/closing tags such as `<size=23px>`, so changing the font size on the TextMeshProUGUI component doesnt do anything. Is there a way to update the sizes set in the opening tags in the stylesheet on runtime?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I was not able to simulate. But I believe it is possible. There is a way to update the sizes set in the opening tags in the stylesheet on runtime.

You can use the TMP_StyleSheet class to access the stylesheet and its properties. You can retrieve the stylesheet from a TMP_Text component's text property. Once you have the stylesheet, you can use the GetStyle function to get the style you want to update, and then update the fontSize property.

Comment: `TMP_Text text = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
TMP_StyleSheet styleSheet = text.textInfo.styleSheet;

TMP_Style style = styleSheet.GetStyle("size");
style.fontSize *= fontSizeModifier;`

This will multiply the font size of the style with the name "size" in the stylesheet by the fontSizeModifier variable.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good starting point! Unfortunately textInfo doesnt have a definition for styleSheet, but I'm able to reference my default styleSheet directly. According to https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.TMP_StyleSheet.html "GetStyle" retrieves "the Style matching the HashCode" (or name if I give it a string parameter).

Comment: Once I get the style, however, I have very limited choice: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.TMP_Style.html?q=TMP_Style

based on this, my best bet would be to query "styleOpeningTagArray" or "styleOpeningDefinition" but both of these only have "get", no "set".

Comment: so I am able to get the opening tags via `styleOpeningDefinition`, and then find and replace the relevant number that denotes the size in the `<size="">` tag but it's a readonly property so I cant set it afterwards, unless I found a way to modify the otherwise read-only script `TMP_Style.cs` (that is "from metadata".

Comment: A possible workaround would be to create a new style sheet at runtime with the updated font sizes, and then assign that new style sheet to your TMP_Text component. This way you can avoid modifying the read-only properties.

But I'm not sure if that will work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately no, because the user settings has a slider for font size, and when the slider is updated, I'd like the font to update dynamically (the slider's value is used as a multiplier, ie font size * multiplier), so I'd potentially need at least 10 styles this way.

For the time being I removed the size tags from the stylesheet and set the font size setting with that multiplier via a script and have a set of reference values for what size each style should be, but it's cumbersome and wish there was just a way to update the stylesheet directly instead! It'd save a lot of headache.